# Cannot close turnbased multiplayer match with Google Play Games

Tags: android, google-play-games

I have a problem closing my game after the last player close the last match. My turn scheme is:

1. Player A
2. Player B
3. Player B
4. Player A
5. Player A
6. Player B

The game works well but in turn "6" when player B try to close the match, player A always see the matsh as "my turn" and not as "completed"

here there is the code thar rules turns and game ended:

```
@Override
    public void onGameEnd(final NMXGameData updatedData) {
        super.onGameEnd(updatedData);

        if (updatedData.getMatchNumber() == NMXGameConfig.MATCHES) {
            boolean iWin = updatedData.getResultPoints()[1] > updatedData.getResultPoints()[0];
            boolean tile = updatedData.getResultPoints()[1] == updatedData.getResultPoints()[0];

            ParticipantResult opponentParticipantResult;
            ParticipantResult myParticipantResult;

            if (tile) {
                opponentParticipantResult = new ParticipantResult(getOpponentId(), ParticipantResult.MATCH_RESULT_TIE, 1);
                myParticipantResult = new ParticipantResult(getCurrentPlayerId(), ParticipantResult.MATCH_RESULT_TIE, 1);
            } else {
                if (iWin) {
                    opponentParticipantResult = new ParticipantResult(getOpponentId(), ParticipantResult.MATCH_RESULT_LOSS, 2);
                    myParticipantResult = new ParticipantResult(getCurrentPlayerId(), ParticipantResult.MATCH_RESULT_WIN, 1);
                } else {
                    opponentParticipantResult = new ParticipantResult(getOpponentId(), ParticipantResult.MATCH_RESULT_WIN, 1);
                    myParticipantResult = new ParticipantResult(getCurrentPlayerId(), ParticipantResult.MATCH_RESULT_LOSS, 2);
                }
            }

            ArrayList<ParticipantResult> participantResultArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            participantResultArrayList.add(opponentParticipantResult);
            participantResultArrayList.add(myParticipantResult);

            Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.finishMatch(getApiClient(), match.getMatchId(), new Gson().toJson(updatedData).getBytes(), opponentParticipantResult, myParticipantResult).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<TurnBasedMultiplayer.UpdateMatchResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(TurnBasedMultiplayer.UpdateMatchResult updateMatchResult) {
                    finish();
                }
            });

        } else if (updatedData.getMatchNumber() < NMXGameConfig.MATCHES) {

            if (getNextPlayerIndex(updatedData.getMatchNumber()) != getNextPlayerIndex(updatedData.getMatchNumber() - 1)) {
                Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.takeTurn(getApiClient(), match.getMatchId(), new Gson().toJson(updatedData).getBytes(), getNextParticipantId());
            } else {
                Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.takeTurn(getApiClient(), match.getMatchId(), new Gson().toJson(updatedData).getBytes(), getCurrentPlayerId());
                startActivity(startNewOnlineGameIntent(this, updatedData, match.getMatchId()));
            }
            finish();
        }


    }

    private String getCurrentPlayerId() {
        return match.getParticipantId(Games.Players.getCurrentPlayerId(getApiClient()));

    }

    private String getOpponentId() {
        for (String id : match.getParticipantIds()) {
            if (!id.equals(getCurrentPlayerId())) {
                return id;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private int getNextPlayerIndex(int nextRoundIndex) {
        nextRoundIndex = nextRoundIndex + 1;
        return (nextRoundIndex / 2) % 2;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

I don't know if that is the desired behavior but when in round 6 player_B calls:

```
Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.finishMatch(getApiClient(), match.getMatchId(), new Gson().toJson(updatedData).getBytes(), opponentParticipantResult, myParticipantResult).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<TurnBasedMultiplayer.UpdateMatchResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(TurnBasedMultiplayer.UpdateMatchResult updateMatchResult) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
```

The turn goes to player_A that see that match as "my turn". At this point player A must call `Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.finishMatch(getApiClient(), match.getMatchId())` (without playing a real game) and the game is completed for both players

Comment: Yes, that's the desired behavior, see [link](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/turnbasedMultiplayer) under Completing a match: "Once a player calls finishMatch()... games services sends a notification to all other match participants to inform them that the match is over. These participants see this match under Your Turn category in their respective match list UIs. At this point, your game can call finishMatch() for these participants to save their final game data. Invoking this method also moves the match to the Completed Matches category in the participant’s match list UI."